# Accediendo con Python a un fichero en path con espacios

Tags: python, rutas

Tengo el fichero "C:\Program Files (x86)\ejecutable.exe", pero al tratar de ejecutarlo con os.system(), como tiene espacios, se produce un error en "C:\Program" porque no lee más allá del primer espacio.

¿Sabéis cómo solventar este problema?

Gracias.

Comment: Entrecomilla la ruta: `os.system(r'"C:\Program Files (x86)\ejecutable.exe"')`. De todas formas `os.system` en la práctica se considera como "deprecated", usa [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) en su lugar.

Comment: @FJSevilla Sería bueno publicaras la respuesta para que sea aceptada por el OP.